# CountDownTimer cancel() not Working

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am new to Android Development and trying to make little Game.
`CountDownTimer.cancel()` is not working for me.

Any Idea?

Thank Your for your Answer!

```
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                maxTime = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timer.setText(String.valueOf(maxTime));
            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };

        if (startTimer == true) {
            cdt.start();
        } else {
            cdt.cancel();
        }
```

Comment: please provide full code, what is `startTimer` ? what is its value? when is it changed?

Comment: are you getting any kind of exception ? Pl provide full code as well as logcat trace in case of any exception.

Comment: Hi gio, Thankx for your Answer. here is the full methord. i`m getting no exception. when it called cancel() methord; happing nothing. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to do an assumption right here because the code doesn't show much! apparently you are using the `countDownTimer` inside your `onCreate` as an inner class so that will trigger the timer when `startTimer == true` and it would create the object no matter what! I guess it would be better to create a global instance of `CountDownTimer`.

And write your code in this way:

```
if(startTimer == true) {
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            maxTime = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            timer.setText(String.valueOf(maxTime));
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start(); //start the countdowntimer
}
else{
    cdt.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thank god, you are the best... I was just about to give up on this .....

Comment: I was calling startTimer method from both onCreate and onResume method. While when I call ctd.cancel(), it stops my one ctd object and other still running. Finally work when I remove startTimer method call from onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Boolean Myboolean = true;
        CountDownTimer MyCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                Log.i("onTick" , String.valueOf((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60));
                if(!Myboolean ) { cancel(); }
            }

        }.start();
```

i had this issue , the CountDownTimer will not cancle with (MyCountDownTimer.cancel();) , the best way is to use Boolean , set the Boolean to false to cancel the CountDownTimer. in any place you want (Myboolean =false;)