# Android : countDownTimer.cancel() not working

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have gone through the following questions

[CountDownTimer cancel() not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730115/countdowntimer-cancel-not-working)

[CountDownTimer.cancel() is not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423848/countdowntimer-cancel-is-not-working-in-android)

Here is the code

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startCountDownTimer();
}

private class MyCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountdownTimer(long timeInMiliSeconds, long interval) {
        super(timeInMiliSeconds, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}

public startCountDownTimer(){
    mCountDownTimer = new MyCountdownTimer(timeInMiliSeconds, Constant.ONE_SECOND);
    countDownTimer.start();
}


public void restartTimer(){
    cancelCountDownTimer();

    // Restarting timer
    mCountDownTimer = new MyCountdownTimer(timeInMiliSeconds, Constant.ONE_SECOND);
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}


public void cancelCountDownTimer() {
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "canceling timer");
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mCountDownTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? When onFinish is called, the time is up (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onFinish()). Cancelling it then isn't of much use

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE sorry that was a mistake i have edited it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JCarlos not quite, Ended up using a different implementation. Actually don't remember in which project I will post a code snippet if I can find it.